# github actions "The key 'concurrency' is not allowed."

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to cancel the previous run when a new run is executed.
So, referring to the https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency document, I added the concurrency keyword.

Below is my sample code.

```
name: test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/**

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
~~~
```

However, when executing the action, an error saying **"The key 'concurrency' is not allowed"** is thrown and it does not work. The examples on google are no different from my sample code. What is the cause?
(If the concurrency keyword is removed, the action works normally.)

Answer (score 0):

Tried the code you provided and it worked for me with no issue. Not sure what the problem is on your side. Are you running this on a GitHub-provided runner or are you self-hosting one? Can't gauge that since you job description is missing. Also do you have a link to the repository maybe?

Something to try would be to add the [concurrency key on the job level instead](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idconcurrency) of the global level. Maybe that changes things for you

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I am using it by registering as a self-hosted runner. Is concurrency possible only with the runner provided by github?
(I can't give you a link because it's a private repo. sorry..)